# Graphic driver question

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.10, nvidia-geforce

I'm using titan xp. 
oneday I accidently do something and  ubuntu screen became so slow and it does not recognize the other secondary screen.

First I thought it is a problem with Nvidia-graphic driver so I try to install the Nvidia- graphics drivers but it failed

Today I reinstall the ubuntu again
now it work find(two screen turn on fine and screen seems recognize the graphics driver) but it seems like nvidia-graphic driver is not installed in this ubuntu.....

so my question is 
1. what is nvidia-graphic driver do?
2. what make ubuntu recognize several different screen and make it faster??

Answer (score 0):

**For the first question 1:** nvidia-graphic driver is a GPU driver. It provider driver support for Nvidia titan xp graphic card.

**For second question 2 :**

A) I thing you are asking about dual monitor. Please follow the below link of display dual monitors: -

[Connect another monitor to your computer](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html)

B)  It is asked in general. Further, like in windows, general question won't work. Because everything is open and you can do anyting with your system. Kindly be more specific.

If you are facing problem in tracking problem, then journalctl and dmesg are your friends. If you want UI support install Gnome logs.

**In general :**

1) Keep the system and driver configuration correct and proper according to your hardware.

2) If everything is working fine, then you don't need to install nvidia-graphic driver. Because, Ubuntu have default Nouveau for any Nvidia GPU card. People try to replace Nouveau with nvidia-graphic driver (Property or third party open source code or non offical code) when they face problem.

3) You can experiment with preload to increase system speed.

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

Configuration file :  /etc/preload.conf

Please make changes with extra care.